# How to align title and current date in the same line in wordpress/php?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a html/php code as shown below:

**Code A:**

```
<header class="entry-header container">
    <?php the_title('<h1 class="entry-title" id="page-entry-title">', '</h1>'); ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

The CSS for the above **html/php** code is:

```
.entry-header {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    background: #3c3f47;
    display: block;
}

.entry-title {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.2rem 0;
}
```

**Code B:**

This is the function I will use to get the current date:

```
echo date('y-m-d')
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering if there is any way to integrate **Code A** and **Code B** so that **title** and **date** are displayed in the same line.

Comment: display: inline-block;

Comment: @Dilek I am wondering if you can make modification in the code.

Comment: Are you asking where you should place echo date in the PHP provided? if so, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your css :

```css
entry-header {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        background: #3c3f47;
    }
    

entry-title {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.2rem 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span class="entry-header">header</span> 
<span class="entry-title">date here</span>

<--Date in your header-->

<header class="entry-header container">
<span class="entry-title">date here </span>
<span class="entry-title"><?php the_title('<h1>', '</h1>'); ?></span>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

see here for example : https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inline-block_span1

Comment: Where should I mention `echo date('y-m-d')` in Code A ?

Comment: @flash you dont need to add class to h1 entry-title will do what you want since h1 is in that class.

Answer (score 1):

Simply just add the echo next to the_title() function and make the h1 tag display inline block so it doesn't take up the entire width of the header. (Added  tags around date for semantics but not necessary).

PHP:

```
<header class="entry-header container">
    <?php the_title('<h1 class="entry-title" id="page-entry-title">', '</h1>'); echo '<span class="entry-date">' . date('y-m-d') . '</span>'; ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

CSS:

```
.entry-header {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    background: #3c3f47;
    display: block;
}

.entry-title {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.2rem 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap in span's or if you want to use h1 tags set display to inline-block

```html
<header class="entry-header container">
    <span>Senate Portal</span>
    <span>July 6 ,1966</span>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```